# compiler error in accessing first and second of pair inside a map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, function-pointers, keyvaluepair

What is the problem in line of code inside inner for loop if else block??
Accessing first and second of a pair inside a map is creating problems

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t; cin>>t;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        int n; cin>>n; int sum = 0;
        unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>> p;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int num; cin>>num;
            if( (p[num].second ).first == 0)
                ( (p[num]).second ).first = i;
            else
                ( (p[num]).second ).second = i;
        }
        unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>> :: iterator it = p.begin();
        for(;it != p.end();it++){
            int diff = abs(it->second.second - it->second.first);
            sum = sum + diff;
        }
        cout<<sum<<endl;

    }
}
```

[image]

These are the errors I get:

```
In function 'int main()':
13:21: error: request for member 'first' in 'p.std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> >::operator[](num).std::pair<int, int>::second', which is of non-class type 'int'


14:21: error: request for member 'first' in 'p.std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> >::operator[](num).std::pair<int, int>::second', which is of non-class type 'int'


16:21: error: request for member 'second' in 'p.std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> >::operator[](num).std::pair<int, int>::second', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems please? Is there a compiler error, or the results are not as you expect?

Comment: compiler error in accesing the first and second of pair inside the map @BoBTFish

Comment: please edit to put the compilation error /inside/ the question.

Comment: `unordered_map<int, pair<int, int>> :: iterator it = p.begin(); for(;it != p.end();it++)` This is one reason we now have `auto` -> `for(auto it = p.begin();it != p.end();it++)`

Comment: IMHO this example shows why it's not a good idea to use `std::pair`. If you get statements like `foo[i].first.second[j].second.first` you have no idea what's happening. Better to make your own struct `struct Foo{ int bar, baz; };`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing up between iterating on a hashtable, and accessing its value with a provided key.

In your first loop, to acess the `pair <int, int>` value, you just do `p[num].first` (first `int` of the `pair`) or `p[num].second`.

It's not like your iterator loop, where `it->first` points to the key, and `it->second.first` & `it->second.second` points to the pair value.